# Specify Isolated COM settings in dependent DLLs or just executable?

Tags: com, ocx, side-by-side

I'm setting the Isolated COM project settings in a C++ VS2005 project to load an ocx component using the Registration-Free Activation method.  If the ocx component is also used in a DLL library my application loads, do I need to set the Isolated COM settings in that DLL project's settings as well?  Or would setting only the main application's embedded manifest be sufficient?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, isolation is per-process, not per-module. So, anything in the application's manifest applies to any process started from that application.

Think of what `CoCreateInstance` needs to do to support reg-free COM -- it needs to find a manifest file somehow and if it's present, *not* go to the registry for activation information.

Since there is no argument to `CoCreateInstance` telling it the path of the manifest, it needs to derive it from context.

There is no real context for a .DLL, but for an .EXE the current process handle can be used to derive the path of the executable, etc., so I suspect that's how they do it.